# Compare 2 MySQL tables with common field, identify data that is only in 1 of the tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Sorry if the subject title is not clear. Here is my situation:

Client has a photo library website with 135,000 JPG files. Each file has a row in a MySQL table called "photos" with fields such as "title", "description", "keywords", "filename" ...

As a housekeeping exercise, I have read the contents of the server where the files are stored, which brings back 135,010 files (i.e. 10 more than we know about). I have stored the filenames of these files in a new table called "housekeeping" and a field called "filename_housekeeping".

So what I now have is the 2 tables. One has 135,000 rows, and contains information about the files we know exist. But, analysis of the server shows there are 135,010 files. So 10 files are "orphans" and are probably a result of a deletion failure in the past.

I would like to identify these 10 files, so I need to compare the 2 tables/fields "photos.filename" v "housekeeping.filename_housekeeping" and show only the 10 rows in "housekeeping" that do not exist in "photos". i.e. I am trying to identify the filenames of the 10 files that are on the server that we don't know about.

Hope this is clear. I have tried some of the solutions to similar questions on stackoverflow but they are not quite right.

Thank you very much.

James.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you rows that only exist in one of the tables but not in the other, avoiding costly joins or recurrent subqueries:

```
SELECT sq.filename 
FROM   (SELECT filename 
        FROM   photos 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT filename_housekeeping AS filename 
        FROM   housekeeping) AS sq 
GROUP  BY sq.filename 
HAVING Count(*) = 1
```

Tested on **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4cfbc2/1)**

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is non-SQL way

```
mysqldump DB TableA > TableA.sql
mysqldump DB TableB > TableB.sql
```

Now open the files and replace "),(" with "),\n(" (i.e. force newlines) as diff expects lines, not long string of data

Then do:

```
diff TableA.sql TableB.sql
```

It should return the different lines

If there is a ID of some sort (its not clear from your question) you might need to remove it from the file prior to comparing

**UPDATED**
So use this:

```
mysql -u USERNAME --password=PASSWORD --database=DATABASE \
--execute='SELECT `FIELD`, `FIELD` FROM `TableA`' -X > TableA.xml

mysql -u USERNAME --password=PASSWORD --database=DATABASE \
--execute='SELECT `FIELD`, `FIELD` FROM `TableB`' -X > TableB.xml
```

And do a diff again, you might need to tidy it, so use `xmllint --format`

Comment: Thank you for your idea. I understand what you mean, but one table has about 25 columns, whereas the other has just 2. So I don't think this will be feasible in this case.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your input. I'm hoping for a MySQL query I can run in SQLYog.

Comment: It would be a waste of time, think of it you are comparing 15,000 rows with 15,010 rows only to find 10 that are missing/duplicate/whatever, its a waste of SQL time to use SQL for this